# NullPointerException on facebook login using servlet

Tags: java, facebook

after solve class notfound exeption i have to find error when i login in face book using given example

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.<init>(ExtensibleClient.java:111)
    com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.<init>(ExtensibleClient.java:99)
    com.google.code.facebookapi.ExtensibleClient.<init>(ExtensibleClient.java:95)
    com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookXmlRestClientBase.<init>(FacebookXmlRestClientBase.java:44)
    com.google.code.facebookapi.FacebookXmlRestClient.<init>(FacebookXmlRestClient.java:10)
    FaceBookCrawl.FacebookUserFilter.doFilter(FacebookUserFilter.java:107)
    FaceBookCrawl.FacebookUserFilter.doPost(FacebookUserFilter.java:181)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is open source; why are you not just examining the source code to answer your question? This is the latest version of [ExtensibleClient](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/source/browse/trunk/facebook-java-api/src/main/java/com/google/code/facebookapi/ExtensibleClient.java). The line numbers are slightly different from the version you are using, but the only obvious source of NPE in a constructor is if you are passing `null` for `secret`.